# How to fix landscape mode HTML5 web app in Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, landscape, screen-orientation

How to fix landscape mode HTML5 web app in Mobile( iphone / android ) using jQuery or JavaScript or any other way ??

Please suggest me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Tell me, what is the wrong with questions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.onorientationchange function` for this

like,

```
function testLandscape()
{
   if($(window).height()<$(window).width())
   { 
       alert('landscape mode');
       return false;
   }  
}
window.onorientationchange=function(){
    testLandscape();//test on changing orientation
}
testLandscape();//test on page loads
```

Comment: Yes.. I adjust screen height and width as per above code. But application will open in landscape mode automatically ? Or have to add any other ?